# Groovy - strange Collection#intersect behaviour

Tags: groovy

I have code like that:

```
def a1 = [[1],[2],[3]]
def a2 = [[2],[3],[4]]
a1.intersect(a2)
```

and as result got:

```
[]
```

After some time of research i found out that elements of lists must be instance of Comparable. In [DefaultGroovyMethods](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L11267) we can see implementation of intersect method. First thing i noted was the collection (TreeSet) used for checking existence of objects in one of our lists (btw. if HashSet used it worked fine).

I checked the [NumberAwareComparator](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/NumberAwareComparator.java) there are two options for checking in compareTo method. The first is the delegation of comparison to another class (eaten exception ?!) and the second is hashCode checking.

The first option [DefaultTypeTransformation](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L542) explained us the behavior. 
We can see that only allowed object to be compare are Comparable in other case we got exception eaten later.

My question is why is it like that? There is lack of information in documentation (or am i wrong?) about it. Did i missed something?

Comment: It used to return the expected result in 2.2.1 - if you expect `[[2], [3]]` rather than `[]`. Maybe https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/4a5bb22d broke it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find it documented.

Feels like a great pull request contribution to the project on github with a change to the existing documentation/javadoc to make this more explicit?

The elements have to be comparable, as otherwise you can't compare them to check for an intersection, but you're right the documentation isn't explicit.

You could write your own implementation like so:

```
Collection.metaClass.equalityIntersect = { Collection other ->
    delegate.findAll { a -> other.find { it == a } }
}
```

So that `a1.equalityIntersect(a2) == [[2], [3]]`

Comment: Do i really need to compare elements (by using Comparable) in case of checking intersection? Cannot be done with HashSet instead of TreeSet?

Comment: You could add a method to the metaClass of Collection (see edited answer)...  Not sure a change to this method would be accepted into Groovy as it would change the existing functionality, but it might be worth raising an issue

Comment: I experimented little and that solution works as well:    List.metaClass.compareTo = { Collection other ->
    delegate[0] <=> other[0]
}
def arr1 = [[1],[2],[3],[5]].collect{it as Comparable}
def arr2 = [[4],[2],[3],[6],[5]].collect{it as Comparable}
arr1.intersect(arr2)                                                                          //Result: [[2], [3], [5]]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been introduced somewhere down the line - haven't pin-pointed it, maybe `2.4.2` or `2.4.2` as per [this commit](https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/4a5bb22d). It used to work in `2.2.1` and `2.4.0` and is broken on `2.4.6`... but it's fixed in `2.4.7`.

```
$ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.4.7 JVM: 1.8.0_92 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
$ groovy intersect.groovy
[[2], [3]]
```

How can such breaking change roll out to a release is a mystery to me. Lack of testing?